# Metadata Navigation Settings by File Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, metadata-navigation, classic-experience

Currently using classic experience on my document library.

I'm using the metadata navigation to filter my files. I want to filter files by the file type, meaning I want to filter and see only the word files, or powerpoint. However, when I go to Metadata Navigation Settings I dont see an option to add filter by file type

New Expereince, you can filter files by file type.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In classic experience, you need to create a custom column "file type" to achieve this.

1. Go to site settings ->site administrator ->term store management, then create new term set(File Type) ->create new term(word、ppt、excel、other)
2. Go to your library settings, create a new column called file type by Managed Metadata type, in the Term Set Settings section choose file type, click OK.
3. Populate data in file type column.
4. Go to your library settings, click Metadata Navigation settings, Available Hierarchy Fields add file type, Available Key Filter Fields add file type, click OK.

Answer (score 0):

This option is only available in the Modern experience.  You could setup a custom search results page that only searches in that library, then you can use the search "File Type" refiners.

Comment: how can I do that? thank you

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I figured it out that there is a way we can filter files based on their file type.

Example on my document library, I only have word and powerpoint files.

[image]